# How can I set event start date and end date in a full calendar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I had downloaded a php full calendar for adding events. Its working fine, but the problem is **when i clicked on a date in calendar to create event**, by default the event end date taking as the following date.

I want the end date to be the selected date only. I am newbie to this `js` and `php`, Please help me how can i sort out this issue. Below is the code

```
<?php
 require_once('bdd.php');
 $sql = "SELECT id, title, start, end, color FROM events ";
$req = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$req->execute();
$events = $req->fetchAll();
?>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Bare - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- FullCalendar -->
<link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />


<!-- Custom CSS -->
<style>
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
    /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}
#calendar {
    max-width: 800px;
}
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Free Calendar</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h1>FullCalendar BS3 PHP MySQL</h1>
            <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>
            <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Event</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>

                      <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>                       
                      <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
                      <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
                      <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
                      <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start date</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">End date</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Event</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title">
                </div>
              </div>                  



              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Color</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color">
                      <option value="">Choose</option>
                      <option style="color:#0071c5;" value="#0071c5">&#9724; Dark blue</option>
                      <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; Turquoise</option>
                      <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; Green</option>                       
                      <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; Yellow</option>
                      <option style="color:#FF8C00;" value="#FF8C00">&#9724; Orange</option>
                      <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; Red</option>
                      <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; Black</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group"> 
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label class="text-danger"><input type="checkbox"  name="delete"> Delete event</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">


          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- FullCalendar -->
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        /*defaultDate: '2018-01-01',*/
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {

            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.bind('dblclick', function() {
                $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
                $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
            });
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

            edit(event);

        },
        eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si 
   changement de longueur

            edit(event);

        },
        events: [
        <?php foreach($events as $event): 

            $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
            $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
            if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else{
                $start = $event['start'];
            }
            if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $end = $end[0];
            }else{
                $end = $event['end'];
            }
        ?>
            {
                id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
            },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        ]
    });

    function edit(event){
        start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        if(event.end){
            end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        }else{
            end = start;
        }

        id =  event.id;

        Event = [];
        Event[0] = id;
        Event[1] = start;
        Event[2] = end;

        $.ajax({
         url: 'editEventDate.php',
         type: "POST",
         data: {Event:Event},
         success: function(rep) {
                if(rep == 'OK'){
                    alert('Saved');
                }else{
                    alert('Could not be saved. try again.'); 
                }
            }
        });
    }

});
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeJPg.png)

Comment: You downloaded it from where? Is there no documentation of what you downloaded?

Comment: i downloaded it from github, from the link https://github.com/jamelbaz/FullCalendar-BS3-PHP-MySQL

Comment: The date should be define here, no? `select: function(start, end) {

            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },` Try to check when `start` and `end` are define and what is  the value, so you can change it, no?

Comment: @ Mickael Leger, when i tried to make any changes in  the sample code written code by you, the entire calendar page is disappearing.  you can refer to this github link github.com/jamelbaz/FullCalendar-BS3-PHP-MySQL –

Comment: anybody kindly help me on this, i got struct on this from last one week. please do the needful.

Comment: please help me on this issue